# iOS, presentViewController causes weird / slow view appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *view = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginForm"];
[self presentViewController:view animated:NO completion:nil];
```

I've also attempted to use the follwoing method with no success:

`[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentViewController:view animated:NO completion:nil];`

```
2017-09-05 14:36:20.490765+0100 dev.phonedivert[393:54771] Warning: Attempt to present <LoginScreen: 0x151e39ff0> on <ViewController: 0x151e0aae0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Regardless of method to show the login view controller, i visibly see this delay / lag in the view controller. Half of the UI elements show, but the rest show after the log returns with the following error:

```
2017-09-05 14:36:31.031448+0100 dev.phonedivert[393:54773] This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes
```

I'm unsure if i have a auto resize option set somewhere, i've disabled any that i can find via storyboard editor.

**Further Investigation:**

```
2017-09-05 13:38:12.137226+0100 dev.phonedivert[8770:1420704] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
```

Constraints are the worst, even when they're all blue they are still wrong?

Comment: Check which thread you are updating the view in. Sounds like it could possibly be a UI being updated in the background issue

Comment: @RyanHeitner i've not used GCD for this. should i be?

Comment: It actually sounds as if you have multiple things causing problems.  The thread issue mentioned above is one but there seems to be something wrong with `self` in `self presentViewController...`; how is it being created/presented?

Comment: If you are using the simulator it could be something as simple as the simulator being in slow animations mode. You do not need to use GCD unless you need to do some heavy processing in the background. Hard to tell what the issue is without more code

Comment: i've tried to use appdelegate to do some work before loading any views. I used `[[NSURLSession *session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)` to determine if i load the view controller, or the login form. I belive from additional logging, that becuase of the asynchronous method of network request, the delegate isn't waiting & just loads the viewcontroller. The viewcontroller itself does a check at ViewDidAppear to determine if it should still show itself, or move to the login form. It is this point at which i am getting issues

Comment: @RyanHeitner I hoped that be the case, but the issues is present when loaded onto actual devices, and disconnected from the debug console

Comment: And if you comment out your NSURLSession call, do you still have issues ?

Comment: *" `[[NSURLSession *session dataTaskWithRequest:request ...` "* --- you *probably* don't want to do that in AppDelegate / didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. If you need to get remote data before deciding which view to show first, create a "please wait" type of view as your initial view. Show a spinner or whatever to indicate the app is working... start your async data request... when you get your data back, show the appropriate view.

Comment: @DonMag This was my concern, one that i was trying to avoid & prove myself wrong. i'll post back once i've re-written